# What is the thread context of a thread that starts several threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm new to mult-threading and at the moment I'm working in an application that creates several threads for a request it receives, as to handle these request A-synchronous. There is a need to share some variable information in this context. Rather than passing this to all the methods and classes that (might) use this information (or some of it) I would like to have a singelton that is accessible by all these classes in the context of this request. Other requests that might run simultaneously will need to have their own variable context. So the singleton needs to be synchronized.
What I'm not sure about is how this context will be shared by the several threads that handle the request since this is started by one but different task are allocated to different threads. I hope this helps to explain it:

```
                /------- a thread --\
request 1 -> A-----------b thread ----- (data is combined) ---- > result 1
              \_________ c thread _/ /
                  \_____ d thread __/
```

A,b,c and d thread need to share some information in the context of request 1. The next request needs its own context.
If I call a synchronized Singleton in class A, will it be available to the other threads? I looked around a bit but most of the information I saw relates to the context of a single thread only. Could somebody provide me with some insight or point me towards the right direction? 
The application uses the javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService for managing the threading.

Comment: There is no need for a singleton. Just create one instance of the context holding class and pass it to all threads. Be sure to make the important things in this class volatile, so all threads will always get the latest state.

Comment: Why is this better? Am I not just passing 'overhead' data to all threads, also too those classes in the threads that don't need the data? For instance, In the request I receive a user role id, I only need this deep in the application where a call is made to another service. All the classes in between (that configure the rest of the request etc.) don't need this info.

Comment: Many people don't know how to use the Singleton Pattern correct, which brought it the name "Anti Pattern". If you know how to handle a Singleton, that's fine, go ahead and use it. Yet, if there are other people working with you in the project, they might or might not know. I prefer to avoid Singletons just because I experienced way too often, how much crap people can do with them.